# Simple function cant be plotted

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psnEY.png)

I'm inexperienced because it's my first time learning it. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please provide your code as text next time, this will make it easier to see what you problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are missing brackets in the second line. It is

```
plt.plot(x, 3+math.exp-x*math.sin(6*x))
```

while it probably should be

```
plt.plot(x, 3+math.exp(-x)*math.sin(6*x))
```

The error could help you with this as you tried to substract `x` (an integer) from `math.exp` (a builtin_function_or_method)